# Group Samplers between a GET and a DELETE Sampler

Tags: testing, jmeter, integration-testing

I'm using JMeter Proxy Server to record series of HTTP requests from a program and JMeter has already transform these HTTP requests to samplers for me. However, I want to group the samplers that are in-between a GET and a DELETE sampler.

To illustrate, the structure of my test plan generate by JMeter is similar to this. However, there are thounsands of requests and their method is not written on their name.

```
- Test plan
-- Recording Controller
--- GET Sampler1
--- POST Sampler2
--- DELETE Sampler3
--- GET Sampler4
--- POST Sampler5
--- DELETE Sampler6
```

Is there a way automatically or semi-automatically arrange the test plan into this structure:

```
- Test plan
--Recording Controller
--- Group1
---- GET Sampler1
---- POST Sampler2
---- DELETE Sampler3
--- Group2
---- GET Sampler4
---- POST Sampler5
---- DELETE Sampler6
```

where every sampler are group between a GET and a DELETE Sampler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left Mouse Click on Samplers you want to group

Right Mouse Click -> Insert Parent -> Logic Controller -> Choose Controller

[image]

Comment: There are thousands of http samplers and their methods are not written on the name. Thus, I have to click the sampler and look at them, which is not very feasible for dealing with large amount of samplers.

Comment: @Alex hold Shift to select range of samplers

Comment: I know I can hold shift to select a range of samplers. The point is I am not able to know  which sampler is GET or DELETE until I check individually by clicking them.

Comment: @alex you can search delete and it'll highlight all delete requests